# Linking OpenCV library in QtCreator Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, qt-creator, linker-errors

I already had OpenCV installed from the arch-repositories, but removed it. Now i installed OpenCV from source [like descriped here](http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/). I have problems linking the libs in the Qt-Creator.pro-file in this way:

```
`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

In the old repository-installation this has worked.

if i manually give it the path like the following everything works fine:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
```

I already added the line `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`  in ~/.bashrc

If i enter the line i want to use in a terminal i get the following output:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_photo -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

Edit: There is also a file /etc/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc containing the following lines:

```
 Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 3.3.0
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videos$
Libs.private: -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-go$
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

I hope someone can help me, so that i can use the short way of linking the libs again.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Do you have a relevant .pc file?

Comment: @Jovasa: the question is why `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` does not work and how to fix this.

Comment: @KjMag there is a fil in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig (opencv.pc); I will post it in the question.